# Lattices where complete joins/meets are countable joins/meets

Tags: lattice-theory

I am looking for information, in particular references, on the following lattice-theoretical property:

L is a complete lattice; for every uncountable subset S of L, there is a countable subset C of S such that the supremum (complete join) of S is the supremum of C, and dually there is a countable subset D of S such that the infimum (complete meet) of S is the infimum of D.

I have indeed an example of such type of lattice, arising from measure theory/functional analysis: the lattice of equivalence classes of measurable functions modulo equality almost everywhere (for a sigma-finite measure).

Comment: An equivalent condition is that there are no strictly increasing or strictly decreasing chains of length $\omega_1$.

Comment: A compact segment in the real numbers is an example of such a lattice...